# Can we change "I’d rather have someone enjoy it" to "I {wanted/want} someone to enjoy it..." without changing the meaning?

Tags: verbs, would-rather

I was going to give something away for free so I said:

> I’d **rather have someone** enjoy it, than to waste it.

I wanted to say that I decided to give it to someone to enjoy it, instead of wasting it.

Firstly, is 'to' correct, being used in the sentence above?

Secondly, can I say:

> I **wanted someone** to enjoy it, than to waste it.

or

> I **want someone** to enjoy it, than to waste it.

instead of the first sentence?

Answer (score 1):

No, *to* is not correct - there is no *to* in the first phrase, so you don't need one in the second.

> I'd rather [verb] than [verb].

If you don't use *rather* in the first phrase, it needs to go in the second.

> I wanted someone to enjoy it, rather than waste it/let it be wasted.

Comment: "I wanted someone to enjoy it, rather than waste it." could mean you were disappointed that the person you gave it to wasted it rather than enjoyed it. (I wanted someone to enjoy it, not waste it.) Switching from "I would" to "I want{ed}" changes the sense. "I would rather be a bird than a worm." doesn't feel the the same to me as "I wanted to be a bird rather than be a worm."

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, I agree that  'let it be wasted' is better.

Comment: Something still troubles me about wanted though. "I was **going to** give something away, so I said "I wanted someone to enjoy it, rather than let it be wasted." isn't right We would use "I wanted" if we had already given something away and were explaining why. It should be "want", shouldn't it?

Comment: @ColleenV You're right. I was concentrating on the use of _than_ rather than the tense.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. So, by the things I’ve found out till now, I know that rather doesn’t need `to`. That’s clear for me now. The tense of verb that should be used is a bit of a bewilderment. So, @ColleenV says that I should use present for it and I think it’s somehow better. `I want to give it away, rather than let it be wasted.`. So, please let me know if there are any other good ways to say this. Secondly, if I want to talk about present, `wanted` can still be correct, letting alone the message conveyed, right?

Comment: Thirdly, if I want to talk about the thing I’ve done in the past, `I gave it away; I wanted it given away, than wasted.` seems the best sentence to me. Can I also say: `I wanted someone to enjoy it, rather than waste it.`? Because as I see from your comments, this tense is somehow conveying the expression of me, not being happy over the thing I wanted to happen, that didn’t. What do you think?

Comment: "I want to give it away" (I haven't done so yet.)  "I wanted to give it away" (Colleen is correct in saying that this would usually mean that I _have_ given it away since then.)

Comment: I said in my answer _If you don't use rather in the first phrase, it needs to go in the second._  You can't say "I wanted it given away than wasted" - it has to be _rather than_.

Comment: @KateBunting Hi again. Yes, my bad for not using `rather` again. So, now it comes down to the meaning of it. Does using `wanted` convey this message that I wanted it to be used, but the person wasted it, or, it means that in past, I wanted to give it away instead of wasting it?

Comment: "I wanted someone to enjoy it" - that was my wish. "...rather than let it be wasted." I understood this to mean "I wasn't going to use it, so it would have been wasted if I had kept it". Colleen pointed out that "I wanted someone to enjoy it, rather than waste it" implies that the person who received it wasted it.